# Maya Python Mash - How can I add a selection set using Maya Mash API (in python)

Tags: maya

Adding the cmds.connectAttr at the end does connect the selection set in Maya in the UI, but that's all it does. It acts as it its not registering.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import MASH.api as mapi

sel = cmds.ls(sl=1, l=1, fl=1)
new_set = cmds.sets(sel, n="custom_set")
  
obj_name = sel[0].split(".")[0]
shape = cmds.listRelatives(obj_name, s=True, f=1)
print(shape)

shape = "pCylinderShape1" #distribute mesh

cmds.select("|pCylinder2") #main mesh MASH

#create a new MASH network
mashNetwork = mapi.Network()
mashNetwork.createNetwork(name="Custom_placement",  geometry="Repro")
shape = "pCylinderShape1"
mashNetwork.meshDistribute(shape, 4)

cmds.connectAttr(new_set+".message", mashNetwork.distribute+".selectionSetMessage")
```

Closest answer I found was [here](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/maya-dynamics/mash-distribute-link-to-selection-set-via-python/td-p/8356748) but I am not a programmer to know what that means.
If anyone can help, I'd much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of investigation I did manage to find the answer from the provided link.
The code I wrote was only the first part of the solution.

```
hasMASHFlag = cmds.objExists('%s.mashOutFilter' % (new_set))
if not hasMASHFlag:
    cmds.addAttr( new_set, longName='mashOutFilter', attributeType='bool' )
cmds.setAttr( '%s.arrangement' % (mashNetwork.distribute), 4 )
cmds.setAttr( '%s.meshType' % (mashNetwork.distribute), 7 )
```

Note sure is needed but I noticed when you connect a selection set by default it has an extra attribute called mashOutFilter.

The part that is needed is the .meshType that makes it work.